# c++ operator == overloading in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I'm wondering why my overloaded == function is not working. I'm confused about the private head. Would the private head be the head of the linked list that was made last? So if I compared the last linked list with the inputted LinkedList then wouldn't it work?

code for append

```
void LL::append(string pName,string phone)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->name = pName;
    newNode->phoneNumber = phone;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *nodePtr = head;
        while (nodePtr->next != nullptr)
        {
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        nodePtr->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

code for deep copy

```
LL::LL(const LL& source)
{
    head = nullptr;
    Node *nodePtr = source.head;
    while(nodePtr)
    {
        append(nodePtr->name,nodePtr->phoneNumber);
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LL list;
    list.append("jack","2");
    list.append("jack2","1");
    list.append("jack3","3");
    list.append("jack4","4");
    list.insertatBegin("notjack","0");
    list.print();
    list.searchByName("jack");
    cout << "cloning------------------" <<endl;
    LL list2(list);
    //list.destroy();
    //list2.append("jack","223");
    list2.print();
    if(list == list2)
    {
        cout << "same" <<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "not same" <<endl;
    }

}
```

.h file

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    string name; //data
    string phoneNumber;
    Node* next;  //pointer to next

};

class LL
{
private:
    Node* head; // list header
public:
    LL();
    ~LL();
    LL(const LL& source);
    void append(string pName,string phone);
    void insertatBegin(string pName,string phone);
    void searchByName(string pName);
    void print();
    void destroy();
    bool operator== (const LL& L1);     
};

#endif
```

cpp file for class functions

```
bool LL::operator == (const LL &L1)
{
    bool status = true;
    Node *nodePtr = L1.head;
    Node *nodePtr2 = head;
    //cout << tmp.head <<endl;
    while (nodePtr != nullptr)
    {
        if (nodePtr == nodePtr2)
        {
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
            nodePtr2 = nodePtr2->next;
        }
        else
        {
            status = false;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: This depends on your copy-constructor. Are you doing a deep copy?

Comment: Are 2 linked-lists equal if they point to the same memory? Or contain the same data values?

Comment: First, you compare just pointers, I guess that is not what you intended to do. Next, you supposed to have a loop in the comparison operator, but there is just a single if.

Comment: You should compare values instead. And this will involve traversing the list starting at the `head` node while all data is the same ending at the end of the list or the first difference whichever comes first.

Comment: Think about what it means for two lists to be equal for a minute. Two lists are equal if they have the same items on the list, in the same order. Now that means your `operator==` must loop through the two lists one item at a time checking to see if the item from one list is the same as the corresponding item on the other list. I'm sure you can see that the code you wrote does nothing like that.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include the while loop. And it is a deep copy.

Comment: nodePtr == nodePtr2 would only be true if they are the same nodes in the same memory. So they would have to be the same list, and you already know a list is equal to itself.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what is your implementation of Copy Constructor if it is working fine then this should work.

```
bool LL::operator==(const LL& L1) const{
if (&L1==this){
    return true;
}
else{
    Node* current = L1.head;
    Node* lhs = this->head;
    while(current != nullptr){
        if(current->name != lhs->name || current->phoneNumber != lhs->phoneNumber)
            return false;
        current = current->next;
        lhs = lhs->next;
    }
    return true;
}}
```

Comment: Can you explain what "this" is referring to.

Comment: this is referring to itself. so that we can make sure that is not it that we are comparing same objects.

Comment: I tried running your code and I still didn't get the expected value. Can you take a look at my copy constructor?

Comment: How can I know that how your append function is working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212808/discussion-between-jaxk-and-mohsan-ali).

Comment: you only incremented the first node pointer so the second one stayed the same while it was comparing. So the result will always be false.If you add `lhs = lhs->next` then it will work. Thank you for your help!